Astra_Camera: Wait for device to connected
I have a TurtleBot hardware. It has an in build Astra Camera. I setup the Astra camera using the this link. After that, I ran the command roslaunch astra_camera astra.launch. I received the output :
[INFO][1720553201.550103010]: Query device
[INFO][1720553202.009764172]: wait for device to connected. 

I received these messages iteratively with different number.
It would be very helpful if someone help me to figure out the problem.
Thank you.
